# jQuery: replacing nested elements in the DOM

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a jQuery function which searches for all divs on the current page which have the class "rounded-corners" and then replaces those divs with a wrapping-table which contains some pretty background images. See below...

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // For all "rounded-corners" div's on the page...
    $("DIV.rounded-corners").each(function ()
    {
        // Copy the contents of the div into a wrapping table.
        var $roundedCornersContainer = $('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="rounded-corners-container"> \
                                            <tr> \
                                                <td class="corner-topleft"></td> \
                                                <td class="corner-topright"></td> \
                                            </tr> \
                                            <tr> \
                                                <td class="original-content" colspan="2">THIS IS WHERE THE CONTENT IS INSERTED</td> \
                                            </tr> \
                                            <tr> \
                                                <td class="corner-bottomleft"></td> \
                                                <td class="corner-bottomright"></td> \
                                            </tr> \
                                        </table>');

        $roundedCornersContainer.find("TD.original-content").append($(this).html());

        // Replace the original "rounded-corners" div with the populated wrapping table.
        $(this).replaceWith($roundedCornersContainer);
    });
});
```

This works great so long as there aren't any nested "rounded-corners" divs. If there are, then only the **outermost div** gets replaced with my wrapping table.

Interestingly enough, when I step through this code with a degugger, ALL of the nested divs are actually retrieved and processed -- they simpy aren't updated on screen. (NB: the outermost div is processed first, then each of the nested children).

- ***Could it be that the DOM elements in the each() function are becoming stale?***
- ***Do I need to explicitly update the DOM somehow at the end of each iteration?***
- ***Or is there a way I can process all divs at once (i.e. not use the each() function)?***

Comment: Can you not add another class to the outer div, and then use that to find your divs? If you do a  `$("div.rounded-corners").each`, then of course it will return all div.rounded-corners even if they are nested in other div.rounded-corners.

Comment: As you use replaceWith , the original inner div.rounded-corners should be already removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this or see in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pP42K/8/)

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // For all "rounded-corners" div's on the page...
    var str = '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="rounded-corners-container"> \
        <tr> \
            <td class="corner-topleft"></td> \
            <td class="corner-topright"></td> \
        </tr> \
        <tr> \
            <td class="original-content" colspan="2">THIS IS WHERE THE CONTENT IS INSERTED</td> \
        </tr> \
        <tr> \
            <td class="corner-bottomleft"></td> \
            <td class="corner-bottomright"></td> \
        </tr> \
    </table>'; 
    $("DIV.rounded-corners").each(function ()
    {

        var tmp = $(this);
        var $roundedCornersContainer = $(str);        
        $roundedCornersContainer.insertAfter(tmp).find("TD.original-content").append(tmp);

    });
});​
```

Comment: Many thanks @Willy. I stared at this for ages and couledn't understand how it was working (even though you supplied proof!). I eventually turned to the jQuery SDK and read that the append() & prepend() functions actually *move* the original elements into the target node.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is by using a recursive function - you pass it a (rounded-corners) DIV object, and first it calls itself on any nested rounded-corners DIVs before replacing itself.

Here's a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/emtSS/3/

and your function above made recursive looks like:

```
function replaceDiv(div) {
 // For all nested "rounded-corners" div's, recursively call this function to replace them first
div.find("DIV.rounded-corners").each(function() {
    replaceDiv($(this));
});
// Copy the contents of the div into a wrapping table.
var $roundedCornersContainer = $('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="rounded-corners-container"> \
                                        <tr> \
                                            <td class="corner-topleft"></td> \
                                            <td class="corner-topright"></td> \
                                        </tr> \
                                        <tr> \
                                            <td class="original-content" colspan="2">THIS IS WHERE THE CONTENT IS INSERTED</td> \
                                        </tr> \
                                        <tr> \
                                            <td class="corner-bottomleft"></td> \
                                            <td class="corner-bottomright"></td> \
                                        </tr> \
                                    </table>');

$roundedCornersContainer.find("TD.original-content").append(div.html());

// Replace the original "rounded-corners" div with the populated wrapping table.
div.replaceWith($roundedCornersContainer);
};​
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestions @soupy1976. I've accepted Willy's answer above only because it uses less code and is uses the more modern jQuery methods to get there. Again, I appreciate your feedback.